# capacity and days off In TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

I need to access capacity and Days off in TFS Database, I have found table "tbl_TeamConfigurationCapacity" in Collection database but i don't know how to get the values from.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the table tbl_TeamConfigurationCapacityDaysOffRange.

BTW:
If you need the whole team days off - it's in the row that [TeamMemberId] = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: hmm ... answer or question? For the latter, please post a ... [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)